# ElastiCache and DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, redis, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, elastic-cache

not able to get my Redis cluster and DynamoDB working  together in the same lambda, if I comment any one other work fine, but together they will give timeout, and Cloudwatch simply does not log anything,

ex `dyamodb.get_item()`, `redis.get()` keep on running if I use both until lambda timed out the snippet below

```
redisclient = redis.Redis(host="redisclxxxxxxxxx.use.cache.amazonaws.com", port=6379, db=0,decode_responses=True)

redisclient.get('name')

table = db.Table('xxxxxxxxxx')
table.get_item(Key={'phoneno': phone, })
```

---

```
            def login(event, context):
                password = json.loads(event['body'])['password']
                phone = json.loads(event['body'])['phone']
                table = db.Table('xxxxxx')
                resp = table.get_item(Key={'phoneno': phone, })
                if 'Item' in resp:
                    if resp['Item']['password'] == password:
                        payload = {'phone': phone, 'password': password}
                        response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps({'token': getToken(payload)})}
                    else:
                        response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps({'error': 'password not match'})}
                else:
                    response = {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps({'message': 'user_not_found sign up now'})}
                return response


            def getToken(payload):
                payload['exp'] = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)
                redisclient = redis.Redis(host="redisxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com", port=6379, db=0,
                                          decode_responses=True)
                redisclient.get('name')
                
                token = jwt.encode(payload, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", algorithm="HS256")
                redisclient.set(token,token)
                print(redisclient.get(token)+'redis')
                return token
```

Comment: can you share the whole code, not just call to services?

Comment: When you change from one to another, you do not change anything else as part of lambda configuration? Like putting it inside a VPC?

Comment: yes didn't change anything they both are in default vpc

Comment: ok, then please update with the whole code.

Comment: I'd suggest to put the `redisclient = redis.Redis(host="redisxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com", port=6379, db=0,decode_responses=True)`outside of the function

Comment: tried the way you suggested same timeout

Answer (score 0):

Want to raise a point that's not discussed in the comments
The timeout maybe due to the lambda function timeout configuration. Increase the lambda timeout configuration.

[image]

Comment: tried that too for 30 sec still no solution

Comment: @Un_stuck How much time the response is taking when you use them individually?

Comment: @Un_stuck api gateway has a limit of 30 seconds, so you will need to have both of these executed within 30 seconds.

Verify both response times of only dynamodb and only redis. You will find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda and DynamoDB are executed in the AWS Public Cloud. Both are services executed in a internet facing environment. The Elastic Cache Cluster, otherwise, is user managed service that runs on your own VPC.